# Share highlighted text similar to Medium/Sitepoint

Tags: share, highlight

Is there any service or javascript plugin to share highlighted text as Medium or Sitepoint does? I would appreciate a service as it may offer some statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Wordpress plugin which has some of the functionality your looking for..

[Highlight and Share Wordpress Plugin](http://highlight-share.creativindie.com/)

Its not free and doesn't look to be as good as what Medium is doing but I just stumbled across it today.. haven't tried it yet.

There's also an open-source project called [Emphasis](http://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/01/11/emphasis-update-and-source/) that is a good place to start fiddling around with stuff if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is interested I've found

http://www.markerly.com/gtc

Pretty cool but still looking for something better.

Comment: Your link is a 404. I tried to find a new source but no luck :/